# SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' ReportList.asp, Line 236, Character 21

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am getting this error message in console when the page loads. The thing to be noted is I don't have line 236 at all in the asp file as well the html from the developer tools. Please suggest me how to resolve this issue. I tried to find whether any unicode is present through notepad++ but no unicode is there in the code. I have attached the code from the developer tools below. Please advise. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><META content="IE=5.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<SCRIPT language="VBScript">

Sub submitForm(intSubmitType)

    ' store the submit type
    frmReportList.intSubmitType.value = intSubmitType

    ' submit form
    frmReportList.submit

End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function ClickImage(n)
{
    var objSrc = window.event.srcElement.style;
    objSrc.posTop = n;
    objSrc.posLeft = n; 
}

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM method="POST" name="frmReportList" action="ReportList.asp"><INPUT name="intSubmitType" 
value="0" type="hidden">
<TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="2" width="600" align="center">
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD><!-- Page heading -->
      <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="400" align="center">
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD colSpan="2">
            <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="400" 
            background="title_block.gif" align="center" height="22">
              <TBODY>
              <TR>
                <TD align="center"><B>Report List for 
              EXS4FAAA</B></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
      <TABLE width="400" align="center">
        <TBODY>
        <TR>
          <TD height="26" colSpan="3" align="CENTER"><IMG src="/msclassicdealer/bin/images/redline.gif" 
            width="600" height="1"></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD bgColor="#c0c0c0" width="100"><B>File Name</B></TD>
          <TD bgColor="#c0c0c0" width="100"><B>File Size</B></TD>
          <TD bgColor="#c0c0c0" width="200"><B>Create Date</B></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\AFRL Registrations for Today_201441184023.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\AFRL Registrations for Today_201441184023.xls">AFRL 
            Registrations for Today_201441184023.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>1/04/2014 18:40:25</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\AFRL Registrations for Today_201441184136.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\AFRL Registrations for Today_201441184136.xls">AFRL 
            Registrations for Today_201441184136.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>1/04/2014 18:41:38</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_2014512151658.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_2014512151658.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_2014512151658.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>12/05/2014 15:16:58</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_2014512151710.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_2014512151710.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_2014512151710.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>12/05/2014 15:17:10</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_2014617141021.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_2014617141021.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_2014617141021.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:10:21</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714106.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714106.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_201461714106.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:10:06</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714722.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714722.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_201461714722.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:07:22</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714849.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714849.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_201461714849.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:08:49</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714953.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714953.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_201461714953.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:09:53</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714958.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Maintenance_201461714958.xls">Dealer 
            Maintenance_201461714958.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>40,4 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:09:58</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201451215183.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201451215183.xls">Dealer 
            Owner Group List_201451215183.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>12/05/2014 15:18:03</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201451215189.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201451215189.xls">Dealer 
            Owner Group List_201451215189.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>12/05/2014 15:18:09</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201461714659.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201461714659.xls">Dealer 
            Owner Group List_201461714659.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:06:59</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201461714839.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201461714839.xls">Dealer 
            Owner Group List_201461714839.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:08:39</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201461714933.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Owner Group List_201461714933.xls">Dealer 
            Owner Group List_201461714933.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:09:33</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Territories_201461714647.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Territories_201461714647.xls">Dealer 
            Territories_201461714647.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:06:47</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Territories_201461714826.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Territories_201461714826.xls">Dealer 
            Territories_201461714826.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:08:26</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Territories_201461714923.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealer Territories_201461714923.xls">Dealer 
            Territories_201461714923.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:09:22</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Area_201461714410.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Area_201461714410.xls">Dealership 
            List by Area_201461714410.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:04:10</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Area_201461714714.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Area_201461714714.xls">Dealership 
            List by Area_201461714714.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:07:14</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Area_201461714944.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Area_201461714944.xls">Dealership 
            List by Area_201461714944.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:09:44</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Region_201461714639.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Region_201461714639.xls">Dealership 
            List by Region_201461714639.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:06:39</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Region_201461714859.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Region_201461714859.xls">Dealership 
            List by Region_201461714859.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:08:59</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Region_20146171497.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Dealership List by Region_20146171497.xls">Dealership 
            List by Region_20146171497.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:08:59</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_2014617135735.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_2014617135735.xls">Full 
            Dealership List_2014617135735.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 13:57:35</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_201461714626.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_201461714626.xls">Full 
            Dealership List_201461714626.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>9,7 kb</TD>
          <TD>17/06/2014 14:06:26</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_2014618113712.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_2014618113712.xls">Full 
            Dealership List_2014618113712.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>10,2 kb</TD>
          <TD>18/06/2014 11:37:11</TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD><INPUT id="chkSelect" name="chkSelect" value="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_201461811386.xls" 
            type="checkbox">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A href="\content\reports\006\HUK\EXS4FAAA\Full Dealership List_201461811386.xls">Full 
            Dealership List_201461811386.xls</A></TD>
          <TD>10,2 kb</TD>
          <TD>18/06/2014 11:38:06</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <TABLE border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="250" align="center">
        <TBODY>
        <TR align="middle">
          <TD><A style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="Call submitForm(1)"><IMG 
            style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative;" onmouseup="ClickImage(0)" 
            onmousedown="ClickImage(2)" border="0" name="Delete" alt="Delete" 
            src="/msclassicdealer/bin/images/buttons/delete.gif" width="30" 
            height="30"></A></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE></FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I loaded your page fine on my local server, but it could be that my browser settings are simply ignoring the error. I think the problem is in your final anchor tag -- the onclick method is calling your vbscript function, but I'm pretty sure you need to explicitly declare that the function is vbscript in the onclick method (JavaScript is assumed, I believe).

So try the following:

```
<A style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="vbscript:call submitForm(1)">
```

If that doesn't work, I would then suggest simply sampling out sections of your page to try and isolate where the problem lies. Just cut a segment of tags/code out (that whole TD that includes the above anchor tag would be where I'd start), and then reload the page. If it works, you know where to focus, and can dive deeper as need be.

But I think the above will cure it.